# Python cannot import a class because it's base module cannot be found

Tags: python, path

I have a folder

```
/app
  __init__.py
  main.py
    /folder
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module_base.py
```

In main.py I try to import a class from module1.py

```
from folder.module1 import ModuleThing
```

**PROBLEM**: I get an error when I try to run main.py saying *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named module_base*

module1.py looks like this

```
from module_base import ModuleBase

class ModuleThing(ModuleBase):
    """
    """< and so on >
```

module_base.py looks like

```
class ModuleBase:
    """
    """< and so on >
```

I can't remember the correct arrangement of **init**.py files and so on to get this right.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Imports are absolute by default. So you could use the absolute form:

`from folder.module_base import ModuleBase`

Or you could use the relative form:

`from .module_base import ModuleBase`

The Python tutorial on [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) is a good resource to learn more.